# How to "connect" a git repository without cloning it first?

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

I got a git repo on bitbucket that was used a few months ago for a php application.

I now have a new server and I would like to connect the local folder of this app on that repository.  Challenge for me is that the local version is now more up to date than the bitbucket version.  I'm newbie on git, and instructions I find always imply that we first clone the repo.  I do not want to overwrite the local files first.

Comment: Is the local directory a git repository itself? (Does it have a `.git` directory in it?) If not where did this code come from? Are you trying to push this new code on top of the older repository?

Comment: New code over older repository indeed.

Comment: Starting from a non-git directory and pushing to a git repository of the same project is a non-trivial (though not difficult) operation. There isn't an automated way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of:

```
git clone {remote-url} .
```

#### Directory Without Git Repo

If you **don't** already have a repo in the directory you're working in then this approach will work:

```
git init
git remote add origin {remote-url}
```

#### Directory With Existing Git Repo

If you **do** already have a repo in the directory you're working in:

```
git remote update origin {remote-url}
```

Now you have a repository that has been cloned, but is connected to your remote origin.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to add or change a remote. To change the default remote use `git remote set-url origin <url>` or to add a new remote use `git remote add`

Comment: This allows you to pull changes into an existing repo (which can be empty) but eventually isn't too different from cloning; at least, and especially, for a non-expert user.

Comment: @tripleee It differs if the current code has a remote of some other repository as opposed to not being git-managed at all or not having local code in the first place. The OP might be in this situation or they might have no git-management of the current code it wasn't clear.

Comment: Using your tips, I made some search for syntax and ended up doing:
`git init` 
(BEcause indeed, the was not .git directory)
Then 
`git remote add Yii-Mailnetwork https://name@bitbucket.org/name/name.git`
I did a push, it answers: Everything up-to-date
However **nothing is really pushed**.

Comment: @Yann de Champlain E-SOFT inc., Did you create any commits to push?

Comment: @YanndeChamplainE-SOFTinc. Are there commits on the existing repository already? as @ikegami says, you need to make a commit to push the data upstream. However if there are existing commits, you are going to have to be a little more careful. Running `git init` and then committing your local changes create a new history which will conflict with preexisting history.

Comment: I was finally able to push my stuff.  However, I've never been able to push it on a new branch.  So I did the init, the remote add, the first commit and then the push.  For the push, I had to use -f because of an error: ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward).  I know it probably sucks to push all the files over my master.  **Thanks for all the help guys!**

Answer (score 4):

Without any Git init or clone you can do this:

```
git ls-remote [url]
```

Here is your output:

```
5fe978a5381f1fbad26a80e682ddd2a401966740    refs/heads/master
d6602ec5194c87b0fc87103ca4d67251c76f233a    refs/tags/v0.99
```

see more here [Git Documentation git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a local (non-git revisioned) directory of some files and a git repository of the same project and you wish to update the git repository with the contents of the local files then you need to clone the repository into its own directory then *manually* copy all the local files on top of the cloned directory and then add, commit and push the new contents/changes to the remote git server.

```
$ git clone https://name@bitbucket.org/name/name.git
# If the directory structures are identical then you might be able to do this with a single `cp`.
$ cp -r /path/to/local/code/* name
$ cd name
$ git status
# will show all the changed files, added files, etc.
```

then you get to use normal git operations to add and commit your changes and then push them all when you are done. You can mass-add and commit the changes if you want one big "updated stuff" commit but I would strongly recommend avoiding that if at all possible (to keep the repository history at least marginally sane and understandable) in which case you get to create atomic commits out of pieces of the changes with `git add -p`, etc. .

Answer (score 2):

Connect remote repository to local source:

```
git init
git remote add origin {remote-repository-url}
```

To change the repository:

```
git remote set-url origin {remote-repository-url}
```